# Log files with "Cannot create tracker" error in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore8

Our site keeps on experiencing downtimes, and it seems like it was using a lot of memory. Log files were full of exceptions like this:

```
4552 21:04:29 ERROR Cannot create tracker.
Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException
Message: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Source: mscorlib
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
at Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework.ModelFactory.GetConcreteType(Type elementType)
at Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework.ModelFactory.CreateElement(Type elementType)
at Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework.ModelFactory.CreateFacet(Type facetType)
at Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework.Faceted.AddFacet(String name, Type type)
at Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework.ModelFactory.CreateContact(ID id, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 facets)
at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactFactory.Create(ID id)
at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager.CreateContact(ID id)
at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.LoadContact.Process(InitializeTrackerArgs args)
at (Object , Object[] )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.EnsureSessionContextPipeline.Run(InitializeTrackerArgs args)
at Sitecore.Analytics.DefaultTracker.EnsureSessionContext()
at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CreateTracker.GetTracker.Process(CreateTrackerArgs args)
at (Object , Object[] )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Initialize()
```

We are using Sitecore 8.2

Answer (score 0):

I had this on a site that received a large amount of traffic (250m hits / week). This patch should help you. https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/032518

Comment: is Sitecore 8.2 supported?

Comment: Yes. You can see on that page it indicates that it applies to versions 7.5 and up, fixed in version 9.0